# PDO query not INSERTING information from textarea

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to insert comments from posts into my database. It's not working, the page refreshes once the button submit button is pressed but no information from the textarea uploads to the database.

Is this the correct way to use the bindParam statement with PDO, and what could be wrong? Can I use the same variable names such as uID and postiD as you see they're defined in 3 querys SELECT and INSERT.

```
PUBLIC FUNCTION Insert_Comment( $uiD, $post_iD, $comment ){
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT com_id,comment FROM comments WHERE uid_fk = :uiD AND msg_id_fk = :post_iD ORDER by com_id DESC limit 1 ");
    $sth->bindParam(":uiD",         $uiD);
    $sth->bindParam(":postiD",      $post_iD);
    $sth->execute();

    $result = $sth->fetchAll();

    if ($comment!=$result['comment']){
        $sth = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO comments (comment, uid_fk,msg_id_fk,ip,created) VALUES ( :comment, :uiD, :postiD, :ip, :time)");
        $sth->bindParam(":comment",     $comment);
        $sth->bindParam(":uiD",         $uiD);
        $sth->bindParam(":postiD",      $post_iD);
        $sth->bindParam(":ip",          $ip);
        $sth->bindParam(":time",        time());

        $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT C.com_id, C.uid_fk, C.comment, C.msg_id_fk, C.created, U.username 
                                FROM comments C, users U 
                                WHERE C.uid_fk = U.uiD 
                                AND C.uid_fk = :uiD 
                                AND C.msg_id_fk = :postiD 
                                ORDER by C.com_id 
                                DESC limit 1");
        $sth->bindParam(":uiD",         $uiD);
        $sth->bindParam(":postiD",      $post_iD);
        $sth->execute();
        $result = $sth->fetchAll();
        return $result;
     } else {
    return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reassigning `$sth`, thus the `INSERT` is never executed, you need to add `$sth->execute();` before the second `SELECT`:

```
    ...
    $sth->bindParam(":ip",          $ip);
    $sth->bindParam(":time",        time());

    $sth->execute();

    $sth = $this->db->prepare(...)
```

Verbose:

```
PUBLIC FUNCTION Insert_Comment( $uiD, $post_iD, $comment ){
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT com_id,comment FROM comments WHERE uid_fk = :uiD AND msg_id_fk = :post_iD ORDER by com_id DESC limit 1 ");
    $sth->bindParam(":uiD",         $uiD);
    $sth->bindParam(":postiD",      $post_iD);
    $sth->execute();

    $result = $sth->fetchAll();

    if ($comment!=$result['comment']){
        $sth = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO comments (comment, uid_fk,msg_id_fk,ip,created) VALUES ( :comment, :uiD, :postiD, :ip, :time)");
        $sth->bindParam(":comment",     $comment);
        $sth->bindParam(":uiD",         $uiD);
        $sth->bindParam(":postiD",      $post_iD);
        $sth->bindParam(":ip",          $ip);
        $sth->bindParam(":time",        time());

        /**
         * Insertion will happen just after executing the statement
         */
        $sth->execute();

        $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT C.com_id, C.uid_fk, C.comment, C.msg_id_fk, C.created, U.username 
                                FROM comments C, users U 
                                WHERE C.uid_fk = U.uiD 
                                AND C.uid_fk = :uiD 
                                AND C.msg_id_fk = :postiD 
                                ORDER by C.com_id 
                                DESC limit 1");
        $sth->bindParam(":uiD",         $uiD);
        $sth->bindParam(":postiD",      $post_iD);
        $sth->execute();
        $result = $sth->fetchAll();
        return $result;
     } else {
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still a bit confused. I understand that I'm reusing the $sth 3 times, so shouldn't I just change the $sth to another name, or with your suggestion I'd remove the first $sth->execute() and just have one in the whole query?

Comment: Updated my answer. After preparing the `INSERT` and binding params, you need to use `$sth->execute();`. After executing the statement, you can use the same variable without problem.

Comment: I see, that has cleared up a lot of things, I appreciate your answer and time!

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite your code like this....putting all the bindParams together in an array, and just executing....condenses it quite a bit, and makes sure that all your `$sth`'s are executing

```
public function Insert_Comment( $uiD, $post_iD, $comment ){
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT com_id,comment FROM comments WHERE uid_fk = :uiD AND msg_id_fk = :post_iD ORDER by com_id DESC limit 1 ");
$sth->execute(array(":uiD"=>$uiD,":postID"=>$postiD));

$result = $sth->fetchAll();

if ($comment!=$result['comment']){
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO comments (comment, uid_fk,msg_id_fk,ip,created) VALUES ( :comment, :uiD, :postiD, :ip, :time)");
    $sth->execute(array(":comment"=>$comment,":uiD"=>$uiD,":postID"=>$postiD,":ip"=>$ip,":time"=>time() ));


    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT C.com_id, C.uid_fk, C.comment, C.msg_id_fk, C.created, U.username 
                            FROM comments C, users U 
                            WHERE C.uid_fk = U.uiD 
                            AND C.uid_fk = :uiD 
                            AND C.msg_id_fk = :postiD 
                            ORDER by C.com_id 
                            DESC limit 1");
    $sth->execute(array(":uiD"=>$uiD,":postID"=>$postiD));
    $result = $sth->fetchAll();
    return $result;
 } else {
  return false;
  }
}
```